# Restrict a group to only view the frontpage/default page of my sharepoint

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups

I've my SharePoint site `https://xxxx.com`. It contains multiple pages and subsite and so on.

Is there a way to restrict the access of a specific group, so they can only view the main page aka `https://xxxx.com`?

Comment: Will that page contain some data from a list or library? if yes, than you will have to allow those users permissions to list/library too so they can see data.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by Target Audiences setting in Page Properties.

[image]

[image]

And then adding the required group for it.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could break the permission inheritance on the pages library and grant permissions to that group only to view the main page.

refer below article for detailed steps on breaking permission inheritance.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782